# update_or_create in a loop only update/creates one row in the database

Tags: python, django

here is my setting model ... basically i store settings as pairs of key-value in multiple rows

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default=''  ,unique=True )
    value = models.TextField(default='')
```

so when i want save settings i want to update or create a row for each key 
(if key already exist update it's value if not create a new row with the given key , value )

so here is my view code

```
    jsetting = request.POST.get('jsetting' , None)
    if(jsetting is not None):
        setting  = json.loads(jsetting)
        for k,v in dict.items(setting):
            print(str(k) +' -> '+ str(v))
            Settings.objects.update_or_create({'key':k , 'value':v})
```

problem is currently it only save or updates the last item in the setting dictionary ... so when it's done looping trough dic i only have 1 row in database !

i've tried to create a new instance of `Setting` in the loop

```
        for k,v in dict.items(setting):
            s = Settings()
            s.objects.update_or_create({'key':k , 'value':v})
```

but apparently i cant do that i get this error

```
Manager isn't accessible via Settings instances
```

Comment: Can you show the value of `jsetting`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `update_or_create`, but according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create), it seems you must pass use one or more keyword argument to get or create the object, in addition to the values to update.

So this might work:

```
Settings.objects.update_or_create(key=k, defaults={'value':v})
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create):

> ```
> update_or_create(defaults=None, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> A convenience method for updating an object with the given `kwargs`, creating a new one if necessary. The `defaults` is a dictionary of `(field, value)` pairs used to update the object.

Therefore:

```
kwargs    - includes the fields which should be used to find if any such row exists in the table
defaults  - includes the fields whose values should be updated.
```

In your case, you need to find if there is an existing row with `key` field and then update the corresponding `value` field:

```
kwargs = {'key': k}          # you need to search using key
defaults = {'value': v}       # you need to update the value

Settings.objects.update_or_create(defaults=defaults, **kwargs)
```

Or, in one line:

```
Settings.objects.update_or_create(defaults={'value': v}, key=k)
```